# Progress Dialog between to activites/intents

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to pass information form one Activity to the other and while doing that I would like to have a progress dialog show. Mainly when the second activity is processing the information.  I have been reading up and the proper way of doing it seems to be asynctask. Or is there another way of doing it?

Here is my code: Activity one

```
    public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                String query = edittext.getText().toString();
                // gets the text and makes sure its a string
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,
                        DissertationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("query1", query);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String query = edittext.getText().toString();
            // gets the text and makes sure its a string

            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,
                    DissertationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("query1", query);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
   }
```

This is the Second activity:

```
      public class DissertationActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public ArrayList<String> book_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

String href = "";
String href1 = "";
String search_Word = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    search_Word = extras.getString("query1");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_1,
            book_Array);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    try {
        Document doc = null;
        Document guestLink = null;

        guestLink = Jsoup.connect("https://aulib.abdn.ac.uk:443/F").get();
        Element link = guestLink.select("p > a").first();
        href1 = link.attr("href");
        href = href1.substring(0, href1.length() - 2); // removes -0 from
                                                        // the

        // href_Array.add(href); //adds href to the array because string
        // wont add to the public var.
        doc = Jsoup.connect(
                href + "&request=" + search_Word
                        + "&find_code=WRD&adjacent=N&x=0&y=0").get();
        // System.out.println(doc);
        Elements headings = doc.select("td:eq(3)");
        // System.out.println(headings);
        for (Element heading : headings) {
            // System.out.println(heading.text());
            String j = heading.text();

            book_Array.add(j);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    book_Array.remove(0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    book_Array.remove(1);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    book_Array.remove(2);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    book_Array.remove("Search");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    book_Array.remove(" | ");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    book_Array.remove(0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int query = position;
            // String text = book_Array.get(position);
            // int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            // Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
            // String.valueOf(position), //shows the postion in the array
            // list
            // duration);
            // toast.show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(DissertationActivity.this,
                    FullDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("href", href);
            intent.putExtra("query1", (int) query);
            intent.putExtra("search_Word", search_Word);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

 }
```

I tried using:

```
       this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Downloading Data...",
            true, false);
```

But that didn't work.

How would I go about, so that it displays a progress dialog in between the activities?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not use AsyncTask? You have three methods to implement:
 
`onPreExecute` - to show progress bar;

`onPostExecute` - to remove progress bar;

`doInBackground` - what should be done;

Comment: Just a tip, your code will be easier to read if you put comments BEFORE the lines that they describe. That way, people will know what you're trying to do before trying to parse the language in their heads.

Comment: Where did you show the dialog? The problem is the dialog is not showing?

Comment: Could someone show me how to use onPreExecute, onPostExecute, and doInBackground?

Answer (score 0):

Calling ProgressDialog.show will block the UI thread. So the progress dialog/bar will not show up until the method has returned. So we can create a thread for our method to run within it. This will avoid blocking the main UI Thread. 
Sample code -

```
ProgressDialog spinnerDialog = ProgressDialog.show(  
Placeholder.this, "","Your text ", true);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    //your method code
    return;
}
}).start();
```

Comment: I tried using the code, I am not sure if it is in the right place though. It displays the progress dialog but it does crash the app after a couple of seconds. I put the 
            ProgressDialog spinnerDialog = ProgressDialog.show(  
    DissertationActivity.this, "","Your text ", true);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

just after the setListAdapter on line 48. Is that right?

Comment: That should work ideally. You can also add a sleep statement as the first line of run method stating the amount of time you wish to show the progress dialog. Method code will follow later